# Loading data from .gz file from remote server to postgresql instance of redshift without using S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to load my .gz files that I have in a remote server, into a redshift database table (postgresql) without loading it first in s3 bucket?

I saw two options:-

1. `"copy <tablename> from program "gzip -d <file location in remote server> with delimeter tab '\t' "` command after connecting to the database. This gave me an error "syntax error at or near program".
2. Could not figure the way out using the psycopg2 library in python. Here is the code that was written for python.

   ```
   import psycopg2
   import gzip
   conn_string="dbname='<>' port='5439' user='<>' password='<>' host='<>'";
   print "Connecting to database\n          ->%s"%(conn_string)
   conn=psycopg2.connect(conn_string);
   cursor=conn.cursor();
   with gzip.open('<gzip filelocation>','r') as l:
       for line in l:
       cursor.execute('copy <table_name from %s with delimiter '\t'", (line,))
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the "INSERT" command. You can read each line from the gzip file and insert it into your table. This way you don't need a S3 bucket because you aren't using the "COPY" command.For example:

```
with gzip.open('<gzipfile>','r') as l:
for line in l:
    b=line.split('\t') # tab delimited
    # Handling null values
    for k in range(len(b)):
        if b[k]=='\N':
            b[k]=None
    b=tuple(b)
    sql= "INSERT INTO"+ " " + <tablename> + " VALUES (" + ",".join(["?"]*(len(b))) + ")"
    cursor.execute(sql,b)
```

Comment: This is a **very bad** idea for Redshift. You'll will only be able to load ~100 rows per second *at best*. If that's fast enough for you then you probably shouldn't be using Redshift. At a minimum you should build up very large `INSERT… VALUES` statements before submitting. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-multi-row-inserts.html

Comment: That is true. It will be slow but only way to avoid S3 ( because you don't have access). Is there a way to optimize insert statements? or "COPY" is the best way to go?

Comment: You can optimize the inserts somewhat by chaining many `VALUES` lines together. `INSERT INTO a (b,c) VALUES (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), … ;`

Answer (score 0):

You can `COPY` directly from a remote host using SSH. For practical purposes that means the remote host needs to be a *nix machine, not Windows.

You still need to use S3 however to store a manifest file that specifies the connection details and the command to run, e.g., your `gzip` command above.

Docs here: [COPY from Remote Host (SSH)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source-ssh.html)